# Why does my bitmap image appears behind the alertdialog?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-alertdialog

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image_person = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
}

public void checkBox_checker(String checkerID, String checkerName, String checkerSurname, String 
checkerDescription, Blob picture) throws SQLException 
{
    int blobLength = (int) picture.length();
    byte[] bytes = picture.getBytes(1,blobLength);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    Log.d(TAG, "Checker box");

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

    final View alertDialog= factory.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
    image_person.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setView(alertDialog);
    builder.setTitle("Information");
    builder.setMessage(message);


    builder.setNegativeButton("Report", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Sample.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that the image is inserted behind the alert dialog and not inside the alert dialog. Can someone help me as to why this is happening?

I have entered the image in the xml file and it does get displayed in the alert dialog. So not too sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly as Hoffman pointed out correctly, I did duplicate the ImageView in the activty_man.xml.

However, the problem still persisted.

After much investigations, I realized I missed a single line of code,

**Before:**

```
image_person = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
```

**After/Correction:**

```
image_person = (ImageView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a separate `ImageView` called `dialog_imageview` inside the layout `activity_main`. Otherwise, the activity wouldn't be able to find a View here:

```
image_person = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
```

which then would cause a Null Pointer Exception a few lines below:

```
image_person.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

To fix all of this, delete the `dialog_imageview` from `activity_main` XML layout.

Then, find the correct `ImageView` in your inflated `sample` layout rather than in the activity by calling `findViewById` on it:

```
final View alertDialog = factory.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
image_person = (ImageView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);
image_person.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Yes I had an ImageView in my activity_main. I deleted this code in the activity_main. I do get a Null pointer exception. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Paul I see you found the final solution yourself. I edited my answer to it's complete.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a "findViewById()" before have Inflated its Layout...
I think you have a "dialog_imageview" in your MainActivity's Layout and then the Image is updated in the wrong ImageView.

You just have to move "image_person = (ImageView)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);" after the "factory.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);" row.

Comment: Still not working. The image stays behind the dialog.